# Unsure of what to do with multiple latitudes

Tags: gis, distance, latitude-longitude, geocode

I'm creating a webapp where I want to do a search by radius based on latitude and longitude. However, if a user enters just they're city and state, a lot of cities will match multiple zipcodes, which in turn will match multiple latitude and longitude points. My question is, what is the recommended way to deal with multiple latitudes? Is taking the average an option? I assumed that would violate principles of distance calculation..

Answer (score 0):

Typically a radius based search is done when you only have one latitude /longitude point. Otherwise, if you have multiple points then they are bound to form a polygon. You can then do bounds calculations to determine if a given point is within the boundaries of the polygon. You could also set a threshold distance outside of the polygon.